# Marker and event in android google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I created this code

it display a map and a marker

```
package com.geoo;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import com.google.android.maps.MapController;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;
import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
{    
    MapView mapView; 
    MapController mc;
    GeoPoint p;

    class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay
    {
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, 
        boolean shadow, long when) 
        {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);                   

            //---translate the GeoPoint to screen pixels---
            Point screenPts = new Point();
            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);

            //---add the marker---
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.pushpin);            
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, screenPts.x, screenPts.y-50, null);         
            return true;
        }
            @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event, MapView mapView) 
        {   
            //---when user lifts his finger---
            if (event.getAction() == 1) {                
                GeoPoint p = mapView.getProjection().fromPixels(
                    (int) event.getX(),
                    (int) event.getY());
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                        p.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + 
                        p.getLongitudeE6() /1E6 , 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }                            
            return false;
        }        
    } 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.localisation);

        mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
        View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

        zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
        mapView.displayZoomControls(true);

        mc = mapView.getController();
        String coordinates[] = {"35.6792", "10.0983"};
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

        p = new GeoPoint(
            (int) (lat * 1E6), 
            (int) (lng * 1E6));

        mc.animateTo(p);
        mc.setZoom(17); 

        //---Add a location marker---
        MapOverlay mapOverlay = new MapOverlay();
        List<Overlay> listOfOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
        listOfOverlays.clear();
        listOfOverlays.add(mapOverlay);        

        mapView.invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}
```

My goal is change the coordinates of the user

```
mc = mapView.getController();
            String coordinates[] = {"35.6792", "10.0983"};
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);
```

how can I set new values(dynamic)? (for example i change longitude and latitude with telnet (`geo fix ......`)

I want the marker change of place when user change place. How can i do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you should make use of location manager and location listeners, which will automatically detect lat long for you,
check this out: [gps location cather](http://www.incurlybraces.com/gps-location-coordinates-android.html)

[answer to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655)